# Using laravel 5.8 with Socialite login Facebook

Tags: laravel, facebook, laravel-socialite

when login by facebook get error on browser :
GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ ClientException (400) Client error: POST https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/oauth/access_token resulted in a 400 Bad Request response: {"error":{"message":"Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this (truncated...)
[li[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOgoW.png)

Comment: If you read error message you will check that domain from where request is made is not included in Facebook application settings.

Comment: Please post the code you have written so that someone can understand the problem better and help you.